# Error when reading a SPSS file that is in Spanish with Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, spss

Good morning!

I am trying to work with a SPSS file (.sav) in Python.

This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_spss('C:/Users/bonif/Documents/CSALUD01.sav')

df.head()
```

I get this error:

```
df=pd.read_spss('C:/Users/bonif/Documents/CSALUD01.sav')
  File "C:\Users\bonif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\spss.py", line 44, in read_spss
    df, _ = pyreadstat.read_sav(
  File "pyreadstat\pyreadstat.pyx", line 342, in pyreadstat.pyreadstat.read_sav
  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 1034, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_conversion
  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 845, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_readstat_parser
  File "pyreadstat\_readstat_parser.pyx", line 775, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.check_exit_status
pyreadstat._readstat_parser.ReadstatError: Unable to convert string to the requested encoding (invalid byte sequence)
```

I figure out that the error may be because there are some words with the letter "ñ" or maybe some words with the following character "á". How may I solve this?

The data base is in this google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P8v5NWE-GdAEJRZdmrp5KiL-DODClmfU?usp=sharing

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

as ti7 suggests, use pyreadstat, and you need to specify the encoding, in this case latin1 will do the trick:

```
>>> import pyreadstat
# This raises an error
>>> df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("CSALUD01.sav")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyreadstat/pyreadstat.pyx", line 342, in pyreadstat.pyreadstat.read_sav
  File "pyreadstat/_readstat_parser.pyx", line 1034, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_conversion
  File "pyreadstat/_readstat_parser.pyx", line 845, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.run_readstat_parser
  File "pyreadstat/_readstat_parser.pyx", line 775, in pyreadstat._readstat_parser.check_exit_status
pyreadstat._readstat_parser.ReadstatError: Unable to convert string to the requested encoding (invalid byte sequence)

# This is fine
>>> df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("CSALUD01.sav", encoding="latin1")
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas calls `pyreadstat` to read SPSS files [src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/io/spss.py)

You may have more luck using it directly, where it has an option to set the encoding

From the docs https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#other-options

> You can set the encoding of the original file manually. The encoding must be a [iconv-compatible encoding](https://gist.github.com/hakre/4188459). This is absolutely necessary if you are handling old xport files with non-ascii characters. Those files do not have stamped the encoding in the file itself, therefore the encoding must be set manually.

```py
import pyreadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(path, encoding=my_encoding)
```

It could also be that you simply don't have iconv installed (which it relies on for encodings), but I doubt it (you would get some other error)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer,it seems like I have not installed iconv; when I try to do "pip install iconv" I get the following error: Installing collected packages: iconv
    Running setup.py install for iconv ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:iconvmodule.c(1): fatal error C1083: Can't open: 'iconv.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x
64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------

Comment: On windows, pyreadstat comes with its own copy of iconv, so no need to install it.